# How to add android in eclipse latest version eclipse juno?

Tags: android, eclipse

Recently i have download latest version of eclipse from  [eclipse site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)  and i just installed it but i couldn't find android in eclipse (In my older version it is under **Project --> Properties --> Android** )
    Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: have u installed the ADT plugin??

Comment: @Renjith thanks for reply.. i dont know how to install ADT plugin in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install the ADT plugin in eclipse

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html